# Actionbar icon size not the same on different platforms

Tags: android

Here is my setup. Two tablets - 7" and 21". The smaller tablet has a higher DPI.
Two png images. Both the images are 36x36. The first image is copied to drawable-ldpi directory and the second image is copied to drawable-mdpi directory. These images are displayed as menu items in the actionbar.

On 21" tablet, both the images are displayed with the same height. The framework leaves about 10% space on the top and on the bottom of the actionbar.

On 7" tablet, the first image appears bigger than the second image. The bottom of the first image aligns with the bottom of the actionbar.

I am trying to understand how the framework calculates the height of the final bitmap to be displayed. I am developing a custom view and need to do a similar calculation. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score -1):

`Two png images. Both the images are 36x36. The first image is copied to drawable-ldpi directory and the second image is copied to drawable-mdpi directory.`

First of all, you have to provide the same image with different sizes per device/screen size.

Then, you should create other folders, for instance `drawable-large` which will handle drawables for large screens like your tablets

[Have a look here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help. But your answer is not relevant to my question. Regards.